# Where is a node defined?

Tags: javascript, dom, reference

A collection is a list of nodes per [W3C DOM Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064) but where is a node defined?  I'm assuming it is an element currently but where is the formal defenition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the DOM level 2 Core specification, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1950641247) . The DOM HTML specs you're looking in contains elements specific to HTML, but it [extends](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1176245063) DOM 2

Comment: @nos DOM Core is at [Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core). It's DOM HTML that is at Level 2.

Comment: Right, and the DOM HTML spec states that it extends level 2, so I'd rather be looking at that and not level 3, yet.

Comment: The DOM Core Level 3 extends/updates Level 2. In this particular case (where we want information about nodes), Level 3 introduces 11 new properties to the Node interface, 7 of which are already cross-browser in the current generation of browsers. It would be unreasonable to look up the Node interface in the Level 2 spec (where those new properties are not mentioned). If you're concerned about the compatibility between DOM HTML Level 2 and DOM Core Level 3, I would be surprised if there is a single compatibility issue between those two.